# Java rest util: Elegant way to built rest urls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently, I'm building urls using string concatenation.

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/bo/" + docId;

HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = this.handleJWT();

restTemplate
    .exchange(
        url,
        HttpMethod.DELETE,
        httpEntity,
        Void.class
    );
```

Is there more elegant to build rest url using java?

Comment: Your end point is hardwired - this will only work on your local machine.  Why do you think this isn't elegant enough?    What would greater elegance look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [UriComponentsBuiler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/bo/{docId}"
UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(url)
            .buildAndExpand(docId)
            .toUriString();
```

And url should be injected from properties.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/bo/{docId}";

restTemplate
.exchange(
    url,
    HttpMethod.DELETE,
    httpEntity,
    Void.class,
    docId
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Hard-coding URLs like you do is certainly not recommended.

Spring Boot Rest allows you to map requests to URLs via annotations like `@RequestMapping`.

In your case a method signature in a with `@RestController` annotated class could like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bo/{docId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void request(@PathVariable("docId") int docId){
   ...
}
```

E.g. entering localhost:8080/bo/123 in your browser would then result in a method call with "123" being the passed parameter.

With this layout you can trigger method calls pretty conveniently. I recommend you to go through this [Spring Boot Rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial.
It provides a good starting point on how to properly set up a Spring Boot application with restful interaction.

Comment: The question asked for an elegant way to build a url without using String concatenation. They did not ask how to build a REST endpoint